# 2D Binpacking using RL

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, bin-packing, stable-baselines

I am working on a project that involves solving a 2D bin packing problem using reinforcement learning (RL). I am facing a challenge with training the RL. It seems that the RL does not learn to improve its performance over time, and it often produces invalid or overlapping solutions. I am not sure what I am doing wrong or what I need to change in my approach.
I am using stable-baselines 3.
Here you can see the main code:

```
env = Area(30,30,{},30)
env.reset()
policy_kwargs = dict(activation_fn=th.nn.ReLU,
                     net_arch=dict(vf=[500, 5000,5000,500], pi=[500, 5000,5000,500]))
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env,policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs, verbose=1,tensorboard_log=logdir,learning_rate=0.001)

start=440000

TIMESTEPS = 10000
iters=1
while True:
    model.learn(total_timesteps=TIMESTEPS, reset_num_timesteps=False,tb_log_name=f'PPO',callback=TensorboardCallback())
    model.env.reset()
    model.save(r"model\PP0"+
               "\Model_"+str(iters*TIMESTEPS+start))
    iters+=1
```

This two segments are from the custom enviroment I created using stable-baselines 3.

```
def return_matrix_of_currenct_layout(self):
    matrix=[]
    for room in self.room_list:
        matrix.append([room.id,room.x1,room.y1,room.x2,room.y2])
    return np.array(matrix,dtype=np.int32)

def step(self,action):
    #Room,x1,y2
    done=False
    room_1_index=action[0]
    x1=action[1]
    y1=action[2]
    self.room_list[room_1_index].update(x1,y1)
    observation=self.return_matrix_of_currenct_layout()

    room_1=self.room_list[room_1_index]
    reward=1

    for room_2 in self.room_list:
        if True==self.check_if_rooms_overlap(room_1,room_2):
            reward-=0.30

        for room_3 in self.room_list:
            if True == self.check_if_rooms_overlap(room_2, room_3):
                reward -= 0.030

    if True==self.check_if_any_room_invalid():
        reward-=0.5

    if False==self.check_if_room_invalid(room_1):
        reward+=0.30000

    if False==self.check_if_any_room_invalid():
        if False==self.check_if_any_room_overlaps():
            done=True
            reward+=10

    self.reward=+reward
    # print(self.reward)
    return observation,reward,done, {}
```

Am i missing something obvious?

The tensorboard log looks like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

- I tried to change the reward function.
- I tried to change the size of the RL

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code within code blocks (```).

Comment: I have taken a look at the images however, and I suggest using a smaller network. This network will take hours or even days to train. I recommend starting small, and increase the network in size if you are not satisfied with the result

Comment: I trained it on my 3070 for 1,5 days and there was no improvement

Comment: I only made the network this large because there was no improvement with smaller networks.